# How to iterate an array of objects or convert the list of objects to array?

Tags: node.js, json, sql-server, angular

I have the following structure, when I call the API from SqlServer:

```
{
  "recordsets": [
    [
      {
        "id_alquiler": 71735,
        "nombre_tipo_exhibidor": "Exhibidores de Temporada",
        "nombre_empresa": "TIOMAE",
        "nombre_estado_alquiler": "Por Montar",
        "marca": "ElTio",
        "nombre_sucursal": "EUAI"
      },
      {
        "id_alquiler": 71736,
        "nombre_tipo_exhibidor": "Exhibidores de Temporada",
        "nombre_empresa": "TIOELTOE",
        "nombre_estado_alquiler": "Por Montar",
        "marca": "Wuayba",
        "nombre_sucursal": "TOBAIE"
      },
```

When I call the API in my .ts component through the explorer in impection it sends me this error "trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed"

I have the interface with the structure and correct typing of the objects either in the Back or in the front in the same order as I call the objects, but still it sends me an error, I know it is because I need to convert the objects, but I have tested in various ways with .map () and .keys () and I don't give, please help. This is the function in the backend that returns the query:

```
export async function listAlq(req: Request, res: Response) {
    console.time('loop')
    try {
        let response:Alquiler = await pool1.query(
            "Select query");   
        console.log(response);
        res.status(200).json(response);
    }
    catch(error) { //Capturando error
       console.error(error, 'Internal server Error', res.status(500));   
    }
    console.timeEnd('loop')
}
```

Service in Angular

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  getAllAlq() {
    return this.http.get<Alquiler[]>('http://localhost:3000/api/alq');
  }
```

Angular component.tsc

```
export class AlquileresComponent implements OnInit {

  alquiler: Alquiler[] = [];

  constructor(
    private dataService: DataService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fetchAlq();
  }

  fetchAlq() {
    this.dataService.getAllAlq()
    .subscribe(alquiler => {
      this.alquiler = alquiler;
      console.log(alquiler);
    });
  }

}
```

and my html

```
<app-alquileres *ngFor="let alq of alquiler.recordsets">
    <div>
        <h5>{{ alq.id_alquiler }}</h5>
        <h5>{{ alq.marca }}</h5>
        <h5>{{ alq.nombre_empresa }}</h5>
        <h5>{{ alq.nombre_estado_alquiler }}</h5>
        <h5>{{ alq.nombre_sucursal }}</h5>
    </div>
</app-alquileres>
```

I am currently running through objects infinitely and I cannot paint objects in the DOM, help please

Comment: check this  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-loop-through-arrays

Comment: i worked thank you very mucho bro<3

Answer (score 1):

I think your objects are nested one array deeper than your html is expecting. 
according to your snippet ...

```
{
  "recordsets": [
    [
      {
        "id_alquiler": 71735,
        "nombre_tipo_exhibidor": "Exhibidores de Temporada",
        "nombre_empresa": "TIOMAE",
        "nombre_estado_alquiler": "Por Montar",
        "marca": "ElTio",
        "nombre_sucursal": "EUAI"
      },
      {
        "id_alquiler": 71736,
        "nombre_tipo_exhibidor": "Exhibidores de Temporada",
        "nombre_empresa": "TIOELTOE",
        "nombre_estado_alquiler": "Por Montar",
        "marca": "Wuayba",
        "nombre_sucursal": "TOBAIE"
      },
```

`alquiler.recordsets` is an array of arrays containing objects.

Not sure what would be easier/better for you to change, the service or the html but I bet if you change your current html to the following, you should see something.

```
<app-alquileres *ngFor="let alq of alquiler.recordsets[0]">
    <div>
        <h5>{{ alq.id_alquiler }}</h5>
        <h5>{{ alq.marca }}</h5>
        <h5>{{ alq.nombre_empresa }}</h5>
        <h5>{{ alq.nombre_estado_alquiler }}</h5>
        <h5>{{ alq.nombre_sucursal }}</h5>
    </div>
</app-alquileres>
```

Comment: you are correct but still not clear what if the data is array of arrays any way I thing this the case here , good job Alberto Lerdo 

Comment: @Alberto Lerdo Try this solution and send me the following error in vs code ERROR in src / app / components / alquiler / alquiler.component.ts (25,32): error TS2339: Property 'recordsets' does not exist on type' Alquiler [] ', i tried changed to type in the service to any, too and nothing  T.T. also send me this msg in the componentes, when add property to alquiler.recordsets[0] Property 'recordsets' does not exist on type 'Alquiler[]'

Answer (score 1):

As per the error says itself it simply says that you are trying to Iterate over and object. Which is not allowed. Why its saying so is basically.. As per your sample data set provided you have `recordsets` which is an array. under `recordsets` itself you have another array.(Take a closer look at the opening `[` square bracket) which basically returning the type of array object which you are trying to iterate over the template and it is not allowed.

**The easiest solution you can do is to have change the template accordingly to match the iteratable elements in the `recordsets` :**

```
<app-alquileres *ngFor="let alq of alquiler.recordsets[0]">
    <div>
        <h5>{{ alq.id_alquiler }}</h5>
        <h5>{{ alq.marca }}</h5>
        <h5>{{ alq.nombre_empresa }}</h5>
        <h5>{{ alq.nombre_estado_alquiler }}</h5>
        <h5>{{ alq.nombre_sucursal }}</h5>
    </div>
</app-alquileres>
```

Once you specify `alquiler.recordsets[0]` like this in your template it will allow your `*ngFor` to Iterate over each object since its actually a Object array element rather than a object of type Array previously.

**Another solution is to assign it on typescript controller :**

```
export class AlquileresComponent implements OnInit {

  alquiler:any;

  constructor(
    private dataService: DataService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fetchAlq();
  }

  fetchAlq() {
    this.dataService.getAllAlq()
    .subscribe(alquiler => {
      this.alquiler = alquiler.recordsets[0];
      console.log(alquiler);
    });
  }
```

**In your template:**

```
<app-alquileres *ngFor="let alq of alquiler">
    <div>
        <h5>{{ alq.id_alquiler }}</h5>
        <h5>{{ alq.marca }}</h5>
        <h5>{{ alq.nombre_empresa }}</h5>
        <h5>{{ alq.nombre_estado_alquiler }}</h5>
        <h5>{{ alq.nombre_sucursal }}</h5>
    </div>
</app-alquileres>
```

Comment:  , this correct but you can use map operator and just return the first item still the same as the previous answer but more clarification 